# How can I write a function in Coq which given a list returns smallest nat not present in the list?

Tags: coq

Coq refuses to accept the below function because no argument is decreasing, but how can I convince it that as the length of `fvs` is finite, function will terminate?

```
Fixpoint generate_unique_name (fvs: list nat) (base: nat) : nat :=
if (isIn fvs base) then (generate_unique_name fvs (S base)) else base.
```

`isIn` returns bool telling whether `base` is in `fvs` or not.

Is there a better way to write the above mentioned function?

Answer (score 2):

If all that you need is a "fresh" natural I'd use:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.
Definition fresh_nat (l : seq nat) := \max_(i <- l) i.+1.

Lemma fresh_natP l : fresh_nat l \notin l.
Proof. (* exercise *)
```

You can also try to define `fresh_nat` as the smallest nat not in `l`, in order to do this you want to explore at most `size l` elements of the ordered version of `l`, and you will either find a non-used number as the first element where that fails the common prefix test. An alternative to sorting test-and-remove. What is you ultimate purpose? See an example of the first approach:

```
Definition fresh_nat (l : seq nat) :=
  let l_s := undup (sort leq l) in
  find (prod_curry xpredC1) (zip (iota 0 (size l_s)) l_s).
```

Beware of the above function thou, I didn't prove it correct ;)

In order to fix your original function, you will have to choose some parameter to decrease. There are actually many possible alternatives.